# Is there any differences between index and indices in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, lucene

Index in Elasticsearch is similar to Database. So what indices point to. Is it same?

Answer (score 10):

indices are the plural form of index. In case of more than One index, we call it indices (indexes can also be used)

Answer (score -9):

Index represents Database (like customer DB) and indices represents table id (like Address table id in Customer DB) - (i.e)

Index is a collection of documents and indices is a document id. In Elastic Search,to search one document, we will use index id or indices id & name .

Comment: You answer is at the very top of this confusion over the google and if the person don't open the link he will remain confuse because of your logic so please remove or improve your answer.